# clase Mysqli_Database.php no me retorna resultados en una consulta preparada

Tags: php, mysql, github

Me encuentro ejecutando el siguiente codigo para hacer una consulta:

```
   public static function myfuncion(){ 
          $conm = new Database();
          $sql = "select `user_nombre` from `".self::$tablename."` where `user_nick` = ?;";
          $conm->prepare($sql);
          $conm->execute("Administrador");
          $query = $conm->results('array');
          return $query;
   }
```

siendo `Database()` la clase que se encuentra en [Mysqli_Database](https://github.com/aaronlord/mysqli/blob/master/database/Mysqli_Database.php) y al hacer un `var_dump(myclasse::myfuncion());` no me regresa resultado, pero si elimino la linea del `...->results('array');` entonces si me regresa el resultado, no se bien por qué sucede ésto. De cualquier forma no es el resultado esperado.

Comment: la classe de [https://github.com/aaronlord/mysqli] dice permitir hacer las consultas preparadas de la forma: $results = $Mysqli_Database
  ->prepare("SELECT `foo` FROM `bar` WHERE `foo` = ? OR `foo` = ?;")
  ->execute("Timmy O'Toole", 2)
  ->results('array');

Answer (score 2):

Dado que estás usando una biblioteca de Github, la documentación de la misma explica que las consultas preparadas deben enviarse así:

```
$results = $Mysqli_Database
    ->prepare("SELECT `foo` FROM `bar` WHERE `foo` = ? OR `foo` = ?;")
    ->execute("Timmy O'Toole", 2)
    ->results('array');
```

Prueba a hacerlo tal y como ellos indican, encadenando métodos:

```
      $conm = new Database();
      $sql = "select `user_nombre` from `".self::$tablename."` where `user_nick` = ?;";
      $results = $conm
        ->prepare($sql)
        ->execute("Administrador");
        ->results('array');
      return $results;
```

---

### Si estuvieras usando tu propia conexión `MySQLi`, el código funcionaría así:

Te faltarían varias cosas:

- usar `bind_param` para pasar el filtro de la consulta
- almacenar el resultado en alguna variable, mediante `bind_result`
- retornar el valor de esa variable

La función debería quedar así:

```
   public static function myfuncion(){ 
          $conm = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");
          $sql = "select `user_nombre` from `".self::$tablename."` where `user_nick` = ?;";
          $user_nick="Administrador";
          $stmt=$conm->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->bind_param("s",$user_nick);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->bind_result($user_nombre);
          return $user_nombre;
   }
```

No está mal comprender cómo funciona PHP por dentro :)

Comment: Tienes toda la razón pero lo que deseo es tener la comodidad de no tener que escribir tanto código por eso uso la classe de github, lo que no comprendo, es si tiene algún error la librería pues me confunde algo la función results().

Comment: @Joel entiendo. En ese caso, puedes revisar el método [en el código fuente de la clase](https://github.com/aaronlord/mysqli/blob/master/database/Mysqli_Database.php#L113). Una de las cosas que podría estar ocurriendo es que el código se esté ejecutando en un servidor que no tenga la librería `mysqln` en cuyo caso el método `get_result` como tal no funcionará. El creador de la librería debió prever esa posibilidad, proporcionando al interno de la misma un sucedáneo de dicho método en caso de faltar el drive `mysqlnd`. Si te interesa probar esa posibilidad, podría darte algunas indicaciones...